# Can I force `man` to do lower case sensitive matching?

Tags: search, man, less, case-sensitivity

When I search man pages, the search is case sensitive, but only with regard to upper case letters.  E.g., `x` will match `x` and `X` whereas `X` only matches `x`.  This is the `man-db` version of man, used on fedora derived systems by default and available on others.  `man man` says the default pager is `less -s`.  `$LESS` is not defined in the environment, my `$PAGER` is just `less`, and I have no aliases for less.

This is not the behaviour when I invoke `less` on its own.

Is there anyway to force lowercase `x` to match only lowercase`x` when using `man`?

Comment: The default is strict case sensitivity. What you described sounds like your `LESS` environment variable contains `-i`.

Comment: What version of `less` do you have? Do you have an alias set for `less`? Is the LESS or LESSOPEN env vars set?
By default a `less` search for `x` only matches `x`, not `X`

Comment: Didn't we already have this Q? I think Hauke asked it, I'll look for it....(slm comes back before the 5 mins. expires on the comment...) This one, not a dup but seems like what you're asking, no? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116395/less-is-always-case-insensitive/116401#116401

Comment: @slm, this was my first reaction too, but as the question owner [participated](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116396) in that question, I suppose he knows about it.

Comment: @manatwork `echo $LESS` = nothing.  Note is it *not* case insensitve -- but it only enforces sensitivity WRT upper case.  @bdowning `alias | grep less` = nothing.  Just noticed it only applies via `man` (it's mandb, btw)., however.  I'm sure I've read about this before somewhere...

Comment: @slm As per that answer toggling `-i` works. I'm going to change the question to refer to `man` specifically and add that as an answer (see previous comment).

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' - thanks that's different now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man is calling Less; the only control at the man level is choosing which options to call Less with.

Less's search case-sensitivity is controlled by two options.

- If `-I` is in effect, then searches are case-insensitive: either `a` or `A` can be used to match both `a` and `A`.
- If `-i` is in effect but not `-I`, then searches are case-insensitive, but only if the pattern contains no uppercase letter.

If you make `-I` a default option for Less, then all searches will be case-insensitive even in man pages.

Man-db passes extra options to the pager via the `LESS` environment variable, which Less interprets in the same way as command line options. The setting is hard-coded at compile time and starts with `-i`. (The value is `"-ix8RmPm%s$PM%s$"` as of Man-db 2.6.2; the `P…$` part is the prompt string.)

If you don't want searches in man pages to be case-sensitive, or if you want them to be always case-insensitive, there is no way to configure this in man-db itself. You can make an alias for `man` or a wrapper script that manipulates the `LESS` enviroment variable, as Man-db prepends its content to the current value if present:

```
alias man='LESS="$LESS -I" man'
```

To turn off the `-i` option and thus make searches always case-sensitive by default in man pages:

```
alias man='LESS="$LESS -+i" man'
```

You can also hard-code a different value for `LESS` by setting the `MANLESS` environment variable, but if you do that, then `man` just sets `LESS` to the value of `MANLESS`, you lose the custom title line (“Manual page `foo(42)`”) and other goodies (in particular, make sure to include `-R` for bold and underline formatting).

Answer (score 1):

This is how `less`'s `-i` (command line switch) "case insensitive" mode works (i.e., it is still sensitive for upper case). As Gilles points out, using this is compiled into man-db.

In addition to the ways indicated in Gilles answer WRT setting an alias `+-i` or a custom `MANLESS`, you can toggle strict case matching once the man page opens up with `-i` (which turns the switch on and off); you will see a little "Case is significant in searches" message and now `x` only matches `x` and `X` only matches `X`.

Man-db's `man` has an `-I` switch, but this applies to the search for the man page -- e.g., by default `man BASH` will give you the bash manual page, whereas `man -I BASH` will not.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there anyway to force lowercase `x` to match only lowercase `x` when using `man`?"

Here's one way

```
man -Tascii manpage |less
```

I don't know the gory details, but the `roff` processing is performing markup and the pager seems to be matching the un-marked up text, even though it is displaying the marked up text.
Very confusing, hopefully an `nroff` guru can explain the pipeline.

Comment: This creates a mess in my GUI terminal (full of `ESC[1m` type sequences).